# Can I attach capture and bubble phase event handler on the same element?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

Can I attach capture and bubble phase event handler (could be different or same function) on the same element?

I tried it and it's working fine.

Is it permitted as per W3C?
I don't see any limitation or restriction mentioned in the DOM3 Event specification.

Could someone please clarify it?

```
var divList = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var eventHandler = function(event){
console.log(event.currentTarget);
}
for(var index=0; index < divList.length; index++){
divList[index].addEventListener('click',eventHandler,true);
divList[index].addEventListener('click',eventHandler,false);
}
```

Comment: What's the point of doing both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, binding events to both phases is [allowed](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/images/eventflow.svg). Here are a few instances where it is very useful:

- Programmatic filling of form fields
- Programmatic queueing of form submit events
- Programmatic syncing of multiple select elements

> Some events, such as focus, don't bubble but can be captured.
> The inline handler on the target element triggers before capture handlers for the target element.
>
> Many newly specified events in the web platform (such as the media events) do not bubble, which is a problem for frameworks like Ember that rely on event delegation. However, the capture API, which was added in IE9, is invoked properly for all events, and does not require a normalization layer. Not only would supporting the capture API allow us to drop the jQuery dependency, but it would allow us to properly handle these non-bubbling events. This would allow you to use events like playing in your components without having to manually set up event listeners.

**References**

- [Domina Github Repo: Readme - Event Propagation](https://github.com/johnbendi/domina#event-propagation)
- [EmberJS RFC: Capture Based Eventing](https://github.com/runspired/rfcs/blob/master/active/0000-capture-based-eventing.md)
- [EmberJS RFC: Internet Explorer](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0045-internet-explorer.md)
- [MDN: Event.eventPhase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/eventPhase)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes but it should be discouraged**, you should handle logic to trigger other events/ call functions in the callback.

It's rare to have a use case where an element requires more than one of the same event type.